# Compatibility of USB-to-parallel port converter

Tags: usb

I use a DOS-program in a Windows-XP command prompt. The file format of that program is not supported by newer versions of the program and my needs are satisfied by this program.

The program is purchased with a parallel port [dongle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongle) used for software-protection. Now I want to upgrade my PC and think about a notebook. Nowadays you don't find any parallel port at any notebook. While I already use a USB-to-serial converter I always had a genuine parallel port.

Do you have any experience with USB-to-parallel converter? Theses dongles are suspected to use features that exceed the normal printer control logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parallel dongle does not event fit on a USB-to-parallel cable, because the first (usually) has a DB25 (pass-trough) Port while the latter has a centronics port - to be connected directly to a printer. These cables can only talk to printers.

A solution for your problem could be a laptop with a docking station. Some docking stations might still have a "real" parallel port.

Otherwise, rule #1 applies: Don't change a running system!

Comment: Don't know, why I should consider this centronics printer connector. But unfortunately no docking station is available to me.